# Error when left joining two databases (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, join, left-join

I have a great problem with joining two MSSQL databases together (on the same server) using LEFT JOIN. I run this SQL from the database OLAB_DB and get the error:

```
The multi-part identifier "OLAP_DB.dbo.OLAP_invoice.UserID" could not be bound.
```

There seem to be a problem with the DB not being able to find itself, and I have no idea of how to solve this. I have double and triple checked the spelling and rewrote the SQL several times, but now I just have to give up and ask for help :(

**This doesn't work:**

```
SELECT TOP 200 
    COALESCE(LTRIM(RTRIM(contact_db.dbo.ContactTable.EmailAdr)),LTRIM(RTRIM(contact_db.dbo.CustomerTable.EmailAdr))) AS EMAIL,
    OLAP_invoice.OrdreLinjeID AS ORDERNO
    OLAP_invoice.SalgsPris AS PRICE,
    OLAP_invoice.UserID AS CONTACTID
FROM OLAP_invoice,contact_db.dbo.CustomerTable
    LEFT JOIN contact_db.dbo.ContactTable 
    ON OLAP_DB.dbo.OLAP_invoice.UserID = contact_db.dbo.ContactTable.UserID
WHERE contact_db.dbo.CustomerTable.ClientID = OLAP_invoice.ClientID
```

But skipping the left join and just getting data from the two different databases works just fine.

**This works just fine:**

```
SELECT TOP 200 
    LTRIM(RTRIM(contact_db.dbo.CustomerTable.EmailAdr)) AS EMAIL,
    LTRIM(RTRIM(contact_db.dbo.ContactTable.UserID)) AS EMAIL2,
    OLAP_invoice.OrdreLinjeID AS ORDERNO
    OLAP_invoice.SalgsPris AS PRICE,
    OLAP_invoice.UserID AS CONTACTID
FROM OLAP_invoice,contact_db.dbo.CustomerTable
WHERE contact_db.dbo.CustomerTable.ClientID = OLAP_invoice.ClientID
AND contact_db.dbo.ContactTable.UserID = OLAP_invoice.UserID
```

The reason I need the LEFT JOIN, is because some orders are not registered with a UserID (only ClientID).
I have checked the access rights and there is no problem to access the fields individually, the problem occurs when I have to compare the values in the LEFT JOIN and specifies the absolute path.

Do you have any idea of what can be wrong?

Comment: You are mixing explicit joins (using the `JOIN` keyword) and implicit joins (in the `WHERE` clause) in your first statement: `FROM OLAP_invoice , contact_db.dbo.CustomerTable` you shouldn't do that.

Comment: Not only should you never mix explict and implict joins (you can often get incorrect reults or errors) But you should never use implicit joins at all, they are a SQL antipattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
SELECT TOP 200   COALESCE(LTRIM(RTRIM(contact_db.dbo.ContactTable.EmailAdr)),LTRIM(RTRIM(contact_db.dbo.CustomerTable.EmailAdr))) AS EMAIL,
        OLAP_invoice.OrdreLinjeID AS ORDERNO
        OLAP_invoice.SalgsPris AS PRICE,
        OLAP_invoice.UserID AS CONTACTID
FROM OLAP_invoice LEFT JOIN contact_db.dbo.ContactTable ON OLAP_DB.dbo.OLAP_invoice.UserID = contact_db.dbo.ContactTable.UserID, contact_db.dbo.CustomerTable
WHERE contact_db.dbo.CustomerTable.ClientID = OLAP_invoice.ClientID
```

Comment: This did work! How embarrassing! Of course I do have to specify the OLAP_invoice first, as that is the table I am left joining against. It took you four minutes to solve an issue I have spent hours on - that's why I love community support! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are selecting from `OLAP_invoice`, but joining to `OLAP_DB.dbo.OLAP_invoice`.  You need to qualify the table exactly the same every time, or use an alias.
So either:

```
FROM OLAP_DB.dbo.OLAP_invoice
left join contact_db.dbo.ContactTable
on OLAP_DB.dbo.OLAP_invoice...
```

OR

```
FROM ROM OLAP_invoice
LEFT JOIN ontact_db.dbo.ContactTable
ON OLAP_invoice...
```

Or you could use an alias as well, less typing that way.

```
FROM OLAP_invoice OI
LEFT JOIN ontact_db.dbo.ContactTable CT
ON OI...
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I try to avoid having multiple tables in my `FROM` without intentionally specifying the type of join.

I find something like this to be much more readable and maintainable :

```
SELECT TOP 200 
    COALESCE( LTRIM(RTRIM(con.EmailAdr)), LTRIM(RTRIM(cus.EmailAdr)) ) AS EMAIL,
    i.OrdreLinjeID AS ORDERNO
    i.SalgsPris AS PRICE,
    i.UserID AS CONTACTID

FROM OLAP_invoice i
    LEFT JOIN contact_db.dbo.CustomerTable cus ON cus.ClientID = i.ClientID
    LEFT JOIN contact_db.dbo.ContactTable con ON con.UserID = i.UserID
```

Comment: I do agree - I had some issues with my aliases though. I intend to clean it up now when it works.